# Calculating Inverse Mills Ratio after Probit

Tags: stata, probit, selection-bias

I need to compute the Inverse Mills Ratio after the probit command in Stata. From [here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1348264-probit-inverse-mills-ratio), I found that `predict IMR1, score`, will calculate it and store it in IMR1. I just wanted to ensure that this is correct. Is there any documentation/paper that specifies this? Stata documentation for probit post estimation doesn't explicitly state the Inverse Mills Ratio. Thanks.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.